# Dynamically adding a page to a multipage more than one multipage on the form

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2016. I have a Userform with 2 mutltipages on the form. I want to add an additional page to the multipage dynamically using VBA.  If I have one multipage, using Multipage1.pages.add works just fine. However, with more than one mutltipage, the form gets stuck and excel wants to restart. How can I add a page to only one the multipages on the userform?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MultiPage1.Pages.Add
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    MultiPage2.Pages.Add
End Sub
```

Comment: Please let us have a look at your code so far

Comment: If I have two Multipages (Multipage1 and Mutlitpage2) on my form. If I used the code below to add pages it will work for commandbutton2, but commandbutton1 will freeze the form.

Comment: It appears if I put both multipages within the same frame it works

Comment: That's an interesting workaround!