# How to add pages to a MultiPage at runtime successfully, without getting run-time errors or object disconnection errors

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, multipage

I'm trying to create a userform which starts with two multipages, one behind the other, which will contain separate type of data, say, one is accounts and the other is marketing. The idea being, if the user clicks the marketing button on the user form, then they get multipage1 and if they click on accounts, they get multipage2.

The issue I'm having is that, if I create the MPs programatically and then later call a funciton to create more pages then I receive the "Object has disconnected from the Clients" error. If I use the approach in this post, i.e. create the MPs to begin with, then I get, Run-Time error, Method Add of object Pages failed. This error ocurs when I try and add a page to mp1. So, I decided to write the code below as a test loop, to show what I'm trying to do. It's basically simulating a user adding 10 new pages to their marketing page. Maybe these will be 10 new marketing schemes, who knows. Then the same for the accounts multipage. the point is, the below is giving the same error when I try and add a page in my actual project. So I'm thinking, if I can fix the code below then I can apply the same fix to my project. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to fix this for two weeks now.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

page_num = 0

Set mp1 = Me.MultiPage1
Set mp2 = Me.MultiPage2

Do
  With mp1
    .Enabled = False
    .Visible = False
  End With
  With mp2
    .Enabled = True
    .Visible = True
    .SetFocus
    .Pages.Add
    .Pages(page_num).Caption = page_num
  End With
  With mp2
    .Enabled = False
    .Visible = False
  End With
  With mp1
    .Enabled = True
    .Visible = True
    .SetFocus
    .Pages.Add
    .Pages(page_num).Caption = page_num
  End With
  page_num = page_num + 1
      
Loop While page_num <> 10
      
End Sub`
```

Comment: To manage several accounts, for example, it does not make sense to create additional pages, but to replace the data in the existing page. In order not to lose any data, you can first write it into a dictionary, for example. If you click the Save button at the end, all data records from the dict are written into the corresponding table. If you click on Cancel, the content of the dictionary is lost. Of course, this mechanism has to be programmed.

Comment: Accounts and Marketing were just examples. Maybe the first MP is fruit and each page is a different type of fruit. The second MP is Veg. The outcome I need is to allow the user to add pages without excel crashing or receiving the run-time errors.

Comment: Adding multipages dynamically is honestly kind of a terrible design choice.  Instead of random examples, what are you actually trying to do? I imagine a Listbox with a set of textboxes to show the properties of the selected listbox item would be a better choice.  Then you would just add new items to the listbox dynamically.

Comment: Each page has a listbox on it. The listbox contains the records specific to that worksheet. The multipage is being used as a way of displaying each worksheet within a listbox. That bit works well. But when a user creates a new worksheet with more and different data on it, I need to create a new page with a new listbox to display the new content. What also does work is, if I build the pages based upon the already existing worksheets then no problem. It's always when I'm trying to add a new page to a multipage at run when I have two multipages.

Comment: If I have just the one then no issues, however, as soon I start working with the second multipage, excel crashes or errors. Actually, what I might try is just using the one multipage and re-purpose it between marketing/accounts. I used two because the column headers are all different but I guess I can just change the listbox properties.

Comment: I seem to remember that working with two or more MultiPage controls is problem.  Actually, I just did a quick test and it always errors out with two MultiPage controls.  As soon as I remove the second one so that I'm left with only one, no problem.  I would suggest you find a different approach.

Comment: Thanks bud, appreciated. I think I'll look into re-using the one multipage for all types of data I need to display.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the easiest way to resolve this problem is to put the multipages inside a Frame! Who knew.

[Dynamically adding a page to a multipage more than one multipage on the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63921155/dynamically-adding-a-page-to-a-multipage-more-than-one-multipage-on-the-form)

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it, and it seems to work fine, cheers!